# Load data in background thread with Python 3

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am a bit frustrated about not being able to solve this seemingly simple problem:

I have a function that takes some time to load data:

```py
def import_data(id):
    time.sleep(5)
    return 'data' + str(id)
```

A `DataModel` class calls this function and manages two datasets.

```py
class DataModel():
    def __init__(self):
        self._data_1 = import_data(1)
        self._data_2 = import_data(2)

    def retrieve_data_1(self):
        return self._data_1

    def retrieve_data_2(self):
        return self._data_2
```

Now, the main UI creates the `DataModel`, calling both `import_data` functions, which blocks it.

```py
def main_ui():
    # This takes 5 seconds for each dataset and blocks the main UI thread
    dm = DataModel()

    # Other stuff is happening. This time could be used to load data in the background
    time.sleep(2)

    # Retrieve the first dataset
    data_1 = dm.retrieve_data_1()

    # User interaction. This time could be used to load even larger datasets
    time.sleep(10)

    # Retrieve the second dataset
    data_2 = dm.retrieve_data_2()
```

I want the datasets to be loaded in the background to reduce the time the UI is blocked.
My idea would be to implement it like this **pseudocode**:

```py
class DataModel():
    def __init__(self):
        self._data_1 = Thread(import_data(1)).start()
        self._data_2 = Thread(import_data(2)).start()

    def retrieve_data_1(self):
        return self._data_1.wait_for_result()

    def retrieve_data_2(self):
        return self._data_2.wait_for_result()
```

The `import_data` functions are called in separate threads and return `Future` objects.
The `retrieve_data` functions either block the main thread waiting for the `Future` to evaluate or return its result instantly.

Is there an easy way to implement this in Python 3.x with `threading` and/or `asyncio`? Thanks in advance!

(Edit: syntax correction)

Comment: Try this `Thread(target=import_data, args=(1,)).start()` stil you will need to wait for the data. You will need to store the thread object and call `.join()` to see if it finished

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With this approach, I had difficulties retrieving the data returned by the threads. Some posts suggested using a queue but I'd favour a direct .result() call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `concurrent.futures` module which is designed exactly for that kind of usage:

```
_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

class DataModel():
    def __init__(self):
        self._data_1 = _pool.submit(import_data, 1)
        self._data_2 = _pool.submit(import_data, 2)

    def retrieve_data_1(self):
        return self._data_1.result()

    def retrieve_data_2(self):
        return self._data_2.result()
```

If your functions are global, and your data serializable, you can even seamlessly switch from `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor` and benefit from true (process-based) parallelism.

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you! By any chance, do you know whether asyncio provides an alternative approach? This should be a typical asyncio problem, but I cannot find an advantage over your proposed solution with threads.

Comment: awesome solution :) as the problem with a threading/queue/get-solution might be that the results dont appear in the right order in queue

Comment: @MarcoK Thanks! It's not at all a typical asyncio problem, although I understand why it seems that way. In older APIs "async" referred to running stuff in the background (in a worker thread or thread pool) and invoking a callback when done. In modern usage, which includes asyncio, async refers to using non-blocking calls across the board and (in Python) avoiding threads altogether. Coroutines are then used as a means to avoid "callback hell", but it means that the whole program must be `async` from top to bottom. Given your description of the problem, asyncio is not a good solution for you.